# update-manager frozen or stuck

Tags: updates

I am working with:

```
core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
codename:   trusty (Studio)
3.13.0-77-lowlatency
```

Today I called update-manager and showed me the list of packages to install: [Packages list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kduUr.png)

I gave the order to download and install and update-manager downloaded the files but froze or stuck when trying to install. This is the image of the frozen process or stuck:[process stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX4M4.png)

I canceled the order of installation and ubuntu I gave a crash message. Anyone knows is happening or what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are seeing changelog, any chance you have installed `apticron` recently?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be trying to show you a changelog of the updates.  To get past it, run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If it tries to show the changelog again, press space repeatedly until you get to the end of the changelog.

Comment: <p>Thanks a lot! <br>I ran the command line orders and know whole is working very well</br></p>